# Global variable is not updated javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have **globe.js**, **demo1.html** , **demo2.html** here im declared **var a = 10;** in the global and then i reassigned the value of variable a in the demo1 **window.a = 20** then i have anchor tag click to redirect to demo2 now im checking the value of a here **alert(a);** still it shows the global variable **value 10** but i have been reassigned in demo1 **showing old value of global** please help me to find out...

Comment: Did you consider timing of variable assignment ?

Comment: Go read [ask] please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global namespace is not persistent across different documents. Use sessionStorage or localStorage.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on my query and i integrated the concept you have said in the answer now it working good...